# SQL Server Merge

Tags: sql-server

I am  uploading the stagingTableB from flatfile which has the accountId as the row identifier, but it isn't an int (I want the row identifier to be an int), so I am thinking if we can add a unique row identifier (or primary key) into our target table with out duplicating the records (Using Merge and Update). Below is my Merge, it seem to work, but it keeps adding records when I execute the package). Any help please?
Here is how I created the target table in SQL server:

```
Create TABLE TableA(
[CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Account ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CustomerName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[City] [varchar](50) NULL,
[State] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Zip] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Sales Rep  ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Group Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Credit Limit] [varchar](50) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is what the staging table look like:

```
Create TABLE StagingTableB(
[Account ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CustomerName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[City] [varchar](50) NULL,
[State] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Zip] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Sales Rep  ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Group Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Credit Limit] [varchar](50) NULL

 )
```

This is the Merge Query

```
MERGE INTO TableA as TARGET
USING StagingTableB as SOURCE
ON
TARGET.[Account ID] = SOURCE.[Account ID]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET   
   TARGET.[Account ID] = SOURCE.[Account ID]
  ,TARGET.[CustomerName] = SOURCE.[CustomerName]
  ,TARGET.[Address] = SOURCE.[Address]
  ,TARGET.[City] = SOURCE.[City]
  ,TARGET.[State] = SOURCE.[State]
  ,TARGET.[Zip] = SOURCE.[Zip]
  ,TARGET.[Sales Rep] = SOURCE.[Sales Rep]
  ,TARGET.[Group Code] = SOURCE.[Group Code]
  ,TARGET.[Credit Limit] = SOURCE.[Credit Limit]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Account ID], [CustomerName], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip], [Sales Rep], [Group Code], [Credit Limit])
 VALUES
       (SOURCE.[Account ID], SOURCE.[CustomerName], SOURCE.[Address], 
 SOURCE.[City], SOURCE.[State], SOURCE.[Zip], SOURCE.[Sales Rep], SOURCE.[Group Code], SOURCE.[Credit Limit]);
```

Comment: What is the data type of [Account ID]? If it is a floating point type, the chances are that the comparison fails most of the times.

Comment: It is Varchar(50), I have created the target table with 
[CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

Comment: You need some details here, otherwise we are guessing. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, if you can take a look at it, that would be so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Dheerendra, would you be able to help? Thank you.

Comment: @Knpane, I have added the answer below. Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger works at statement level. Hence when "Merge" is used trigger is fired for all the DML operations that have been involved in the merge statement. Instead, transform your code to below to avoid unnecessary inserts from Trigger.

```
 UPDATE Res1
 SET 
 [CustomerName] = Res2.[CustomerName]
 ,[Address] = Res2.[Address]
 ,[City] = Res2.[City]
 ,[State] = Res2.[State]
 ,[Zip] = Res2.[Zip]
 ,[Sales Rep] = Res2.[Sales Rep]
 ,[Group Code] = Res2.[Group Code]
 ,[Credit Limit] = Res2.[Credit Limit]
 FROM TableA Res1
 JOIN StagingTableB Res2 ON Res2.[Account ID] = Res1.[Account ID]

INSERT INTO TableA([Account ID], [CustomerName], [Address], [City], [State], [Zip], [Sales Rep], [Group Code], [Credit Limit])
SELECT 
 Res1.[Account ID]
,Res1.[CustomerName]
,Res1.[Address]
,Res1.[City]
,Res1.[State]
,Res1.[Zip]
,Res1.[Sales Rep]
,Res1.[Group Code]
,Res1.[Credit Limit]
FROM StagingTableB Res1
LEFT JOIN TableA Res2 ON Res2.[Account ID] = Res1.[Account ID]
WHERE Res2.[Account ID] IS NULL
```